# Update sql with a loop (PDO)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

If somebody would please take a look at my code and tell what to do with it. I thought it was right but obviously it is not.

```
<? require_once("dblogin.php");
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM country_city_zip WHERE country = US");
$sth->execute();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

$sql ="UPDATE country_city_zip SET uni = '".$row['country']."-".$row['zip']."' WHERE country = '".$row['country']."' AND zip = '".$row['zip']."'"; 
$count = $conn->exec($sql);

} ?>
```

I want to create a unique ID based on the country code and the zip code: ex. US-28172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE country_city_zip SET uni = Concat(country,'-',zip)
```

No need for a loop...

Comment: So basically you just want me to do like this:
$sql = "UPDATE country_city_zip SET uni = Concat(country,'-',zip)";
$count = $conn->exec($sql);

Comment: Yep... Never test out proposed solutions on real data though... Or at least have a backup available... Cant be too safe.

Comment: This was actually the solution.. somehow.. I choose not to create a script to do it for me.. Because when I just typed that sentence you wrote - into the SQL field in the database it did exactly what I wanted.. i t just seems to be difficult if you want a script to do it for you... Thanks!

Comment: The query suggested by @BrianAdkins will update all the rows in your table. In the select statement above you seem to fetch records for which the value of the country column is "US", so I would suggest that you add a where clause to the query.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query

```
$sql= "UPDATE country_city_zip SET uni = '".concat($row['country'],"-",$row['zip'])."' WHERE country = '".$row['country']."' AND zip = '".$row['zip']."'";
```

I assume that you have problem in the sql query and based on i will post my answer

I hope problem is solved and you get any problem then let me know..

Comment: I don't seem to get any problems, but it still won't update the data in the table.

Comment: please echo your query and check what value are come and still you are not get then put the query over here @Philip Jens Bramsted

Comment: it doesn't do anything.. but it works when I just use the sentence in the SQL field in the Database instead... No script needed. Thanks anyway..